# How to make a toString() method for a 2D Array of Cells using the toString() method of Cell?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, tostring

My task is to implement Conway's Game of Life, but I'm stuck in representing my game-map (a 2D Array of Cells) in the `toString()` method.
My toString() method:

```java
public String toString() {
    int h;
    int j;
    String str;
    str = null;
    String[][] stringArray = new String[map.length][map.length];
    for (h = 0; h < getWidth(); h++) {
        for (j = 0; j < getHeight(); j++) {
            Cell i = getCell(h, j);
            stringArray[h][j] = i.toString() + " ";
        }
    }
    int k;
    int m;
    for (k = 0; k < stringArray.length; k++) {
        for (m = 0; m < stringArray.length; m++) {
            str = stringArray[k][m];
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

And as you see I need to call the cell specific `toString()` method as part of the task.
This `toString()` method looks like this:

```java
public String toString() {
    if (status == ECellStatus.DEAD) {
        return ".";
    } else {
        return "#";
    }
}
```

In the actual code I only get the representation of the last cell but I want to print it like that:

```
. . . . .  
. . # . .  
. . . # .  
. # # # .  
. . . . .
```

I hope somebody can help me out.

Comment: Seems like you need to do `str += stringArray[k][m];`

Comment: Also add "\n" after each row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second for-loop, you are reassigning `str` to the current Cell's `toString` rather than appending/adding on to it, which is probably what you intended to do.

To append to `str`, you can do:

```java
for (k = 0; k < stringArray.length; k++) {
    for (m = 0; m < stringArray.length; m++) {
        str += stringArray[k][m];
    }
}
```

This will also require you to initialize `str` to a non-null value, so instead of
`str = null;` you will need to do `str = "";` or some equivalent of it.

Comment: The result I get is then this: . . . . . . . . # . . # . # . . . # # . . . . . . But I want to give it out as 2D-Array. It should exactly look like above how can I do that?

Comment: Ah, I missed that that would happen! @Malone2409 This is because you need to add on a newline character after every row in order for it to appear as that block structure.  In the second for-loop, after the inner for-loop but still inside the outer for-loop you can add a `str += "\n";` line